# Better way to add a new line in html using if

Tags: python, html, html-email

I'm working in this function with html, i'm pretty new on this. I'm using python to generated a body email and when i click on the checkboxes in the application should add each category in the email.

The problem is, the way i've found to make it work was set the paragraph state to none and make invisble and then in each if replace this information and add the specific scenario.

How can i make this more clean and instead of using the display option for my paragraph i can add him in each if

```
def update_body_mail_email():
    body_mail = '''<html>
                        <head>
                            <meta charset="UTF-8">
                            <title>Your Email Title</title>
                            </head>
                            <body>
                            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                             <tr>
                               <td width="510" style="width:382.75pt;background:#0076CE;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;
                                height:69.55pt">
                                <p class="MsoNormal"><a name="_MailAutoSig"><span style="font-size:15.0pt;
                                font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:#F2F2F2;mso-no-proof:yes"> Notification</span><span style="mso-no-proof:yes"><o:p></o:p></span></a></p>
                             </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 40px 30px 40px 30px;">
                                    <p style="font-size: 16px; color: #666666;">Dear CC,</p>
                                    <p style="font-size: 16px; color: #666666;">RITMXXXXXXX and the following items need to be provided and to be attached in the RITMXXXXXXX</p>
                                    <p id="invisible_1" style="display: none;">Documents</p>
                                    <p id="invisible_2" style="display: none;">Descriptions</p>
                                    <p id="invisible_3" style="display: none;">Configuration_item</p>
                                    <p id="invisible_4" style="display: none;">Category</p>
                                    <p style="font-size: 16px; color: #666666;">Best regards,<br></p>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            </body>
                            </html>
    '''    

    if checkbox_documents.get():
        check_sub()
        body_mail = body_mail.replace('<p id="invisible_1" style="display: none;">Documents</p>', '''
        <p style="font-size: 16px; color: #666666"><strong>Documents to be attached to Request:</strong></p>
            <ul>
            <li style="font-size: 16px; color: #666666"><strong>Implementation Instructions:</strong> Explain in detail how the change is deployed, roles or groups involved, and tools used.
            </ul>
        '''
        )

        

    if checkbox_description.get():
        body_mail = body_mail.replace('<p id="invisible_2" style="display: none;">Descriptions</p>', '''
        <p style="font-size: 16px; color: #666666"><strong>Description: </strong></p>
            <ul>
            <li style="font-size: 16px; color: #666666">What is Scope of this Standard change activity. Provide detail, clear and concise description in 2 or 3 sentences of what is being deployed.</li>
        '''
    )
    
    if checkbox_configuration_item.get():
        body_mail = body_mail.replace('<p id="invisible_3" style="display: none;">Configuration_item</p>','''
        <p style="font-size: 16px; color: #666666"><strong>List of Config:<strong></p>
        '''
    )
        
    if checkbox_category.get():
        body_mail = body_mail.replace('<p id="invisible_4" style="display: none;">Category</p>', '''       
        <p style="font-size: 16px; color: #666666"><strong>Standard Type [choose one of the below]:</strong></p>
            <ul>
            <li style="font-size: 16px; color: #666666">Application – Code</li>
            <li style="font-size: 16px; color: #666666">Application &amp; Database – Code</li>
            </ul>
        ''')
    
    return body_mail
```

Comment: The simplest way is to use an f-string.  Build your optional sections in strings, then do `f'''... {optional1} ... {optional2}'''`.  However, it really seems like you need a templating language.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a templating language like [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/). For example, you can conditionally include html like:

```
...
{% if checkbox_documents %}
<p style="font-size: 16px; color: #666666">
<strong>Documents to be attached to Request:</strong>
</p>
<ul>
  <li style="font-size: 16px; color: #666666">
    <strong>Implementation Instructions:</strong> Explain in detail how the change is deployed, roles or groups involved, and tools used.
</ul>
{% endif %}
...
```